# Building Anonymous type from querystring

Tags: model-view-controller, extension-methods, anonymous-types

I was wondering if anyone had experience dynamically building an anonymous type from a query string with the ability to exclude specifc values

For example:
Given the querystring resulting in a results screen ?t1=sadfasdf&t2=sdafasdfasdf&t3=sdfsadfasf&t4=dfasdfasdf

I want to provide the following links

Action?t1=sadfasdf&t2=sdafasdfasdf&t3=sdfsadfasf&t4=dfasdfasdf

Action?t1=Suggestion&t2=sdafasdfasdf&t3=sdfsadfasf&t4=dfasdfasdf

Action?t1=sadfasdf&t2=Suggestion&t3=sdfsadfasf&t4=dfasdfasdf

but if an addtional parameter is added to the querystring, I would like the action links to automatically pass the value to the next action

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use an anonymous types to pass action parameters, that's a convenience. You can use a `RouteValueDictionary` every mvc Action method has an overload that takes a `RouteValueDictionary` instead, and you can get the current values from `Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values`